# matplotlib time series from dictionary and datetime

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to understand how the time series of matplotlib works.

Unfortunately, this [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date_index_formatter.html) just load data straight from a file using bumpy, which makes it very cryptic for non-fluent numpy adepts.

From the doc:

```
with cbook.get_sample_data('goog.npz') as datafile:
    r = np.load(datafile)['price_data'].view(np.recarray)
r = r[-30:]  # get the last 30 days
# Matplotlib works better with datetime.datetime than np.datetime64, but the
# latter is more portable.
date = r.date.astype('O')
```

In my case, I have a dictionary of datetime (key) and int, which I can transform to an array or list, but I wasn't quite successful to get anything that pyplot would take and the doc isn't much of help, especially for timeseries.

```
def toArray(dict):  
    data = list(dict.items())
    return np.array(data)
>>>
 [datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 16, 44) -13]
 [datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 16, 45) 7]
 [datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 16, 46) -11]
 [datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 16, 47) -75]
 [datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 16, 48) -41]
 [datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 16, 49) -39]
 [datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 16, 50) -4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important part is to split X axis from Y axis (in your case - dates from values). Using your function `toArray()` to retrieve data, the following code produces a desired result:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = toArray(your_dict)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

dates = [x[0] for x in data]
values = [x[1] for x in data]

ax.plot(dates, values, 'o-')
ax.set_title("Default")
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Note how we split data from 2D array of dates and values into two 1D arrays `dates` and `values`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was going into some crazy stuff, seeing your solution is so neat.